# Printing a particular hexadecimal value in character representation

Tags: c, printf, control-characters

When trying to use `'\x05'` in a string, the compiled C code seems to behave oddly when handling the value.

For instance when using the following string:

```
char *weird = "\x04\x68\x65\x79\x79\x03\x6e\x65\x74\x05\x6c\x6f\x63\x61\x6c\x00";
```

When printing each character of the string, the `'\x05'` is not corresponding to the integer 5, whereas the `'\x04'` and `'\x03'` are corresponding to the integers 4 and 3 respectively.

The following for loop demonstrates the problem:

```
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(question); i++){
    printf("question[%d] = %c\n", i, question[i]);
}
```

Output:

[image: 0x05]

Any ideas why this specific case of `'\x05'` is so troublesome?

Comment: It behaves just fine. 3 and 4 don’t correspond to any integers. Your font just shows them that way.

Comment: Are you trying to print the character '5'? If so, '\x05' is not what you're looking for. The ASCII code for '5' is '\x35'.

Comment: `0x03` is `ETX` (end of text), `0x04` is `EOT` (end of transmission) and `0x05` is `ENQ` (enquiry). These are not printable characters, but [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character).

Comment: "Are" and "are not" printable depends on what the OP's terminal is designed to handle. Obviously, on OP's characters they *are* – whether they *should* is something else. I assume it's for convenience that something is shown, rather than "nothing" – or a total system crash.

Comment: Assuming the screenshot is exactly what that code produces, it's more weird that the text changed. Try explaining *that*.

Comment: Tip: To add clarity to what is printed, surround by sentinel characters --> `printf("question[%d] = [%c]\n", i, question[i]);`  Add `[]`.  Perhaps `'\0x05'` is printing a space?  Better yet, try `for(int i = 0; i <= 48; i++) {
    printf("%2d = [%c]\n", i, i);
}`

Answer (score 4):

`%c` format specifier is for the printable character representation for the corresponding integer value supplied as argument. As per the ASCII encoding, neither `0x03`, `0x04` or `0x05` is a printable value!!

For sake of confirmation, you can pass the same value to **[`isprint()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isprint)** before attempting to print that. In case you chose to print it anyway, the "display" finally depends on how your terminal chooses to *interpret* the display.

Here's some references ([1](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/idp5.1/topics/reference/general/intrusion-detection-prevention-custom-attack-object-extended-ascii.html), [2](https://web.itu.edu.tr/sgunduz/courses/mikroisl/ascii.html)) which lists printable and non-printable ASCII values

Comment: But OP's output proves that 3 and 4 *are* printable.

Comment: @usr2564301 Nope, I wont claim that. :)

Comment: @usr2564301 that's obviously not true.

Comment: @usr2564301 they *might* be printable.

Comment: OK, let's say that ASCII is not defining *how* these are printable.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: exactly. Therefore it's left to the terminal implementation what to do with "unprintables". But the `5` code *does* get processed by OP's terminal, else there would be a `5` glyphlet as well.

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption is wrong. ASCII codes 3, 4, and 5 do *not* correspond to (visible) integers `3`, `4`, and `5`.

What you are seeing is your local terminal's *translation* of what it thinks you mean to print:

1. It does not try to interpret the codes `3` and `4`. These correspond to ASCII control characters `End of Text` and `End of Transmission`, but your terminal chooses to not handle them. Therefore, it writes these two codes literally into the output stream, which looks up a suitable font to display them. In modern (Unicode) fonts, there are no characters for these characters because they are not *supposed* to be "printed". However, some terminals are aware of that and provide a fall-back so you can at least see something.
2. The code `5`, on the other hand, *is* interpreted by your terminal: "Signal intended to trigger a response at the receiving end, to see if it is still present." The terminal sends that signal, receives (most likely) a "yes" answer – yes, the output stream is active – and continues outputting the rest of the text. As it is a signal and not a character, nothing is displayed.

This behavior is not unique for the `0x05` code. You don't mention it in your question, but you seem not suprised to get a new line when you "print" `\n`' *even though* it sends a code `0x0A` to the output stream. And you do *not* get a `10` on screen but the cursor moves down a line. Again, this is because that code gets interpreted by the terminal to take some specific action.

Answer (score 0):

It is completelly ok. `\x05` is not printable character in ASCII table that's why you see strange character.

`%c` expects printable character and your is not.

[List of printable ASCII characters](http://facweb.cs.depaul.edu/sjost/it212/documents/ascii-pr.htm)

Comment: `%c` expects an `int` (promoted in the variadic function) but it is the OS which dictates whether it is printable.

Comment: @WeatherVane To be even more pedantic - it's the terminal who is dictating.

Comment: @EugeneSh. the terminal is implemented by the OS.

Comment: @WeatherVane Not necessarily. You can have a bare-metal C project sending these over serial port to some serial terminal emulating whatever standard (VT100, VT50, some custom, you name it)